# Execute function only once - Depending conditions

Tags: javascript

**I know how to execute a function once, this is not the question**

First, this is my code

```
 var executed1 = false;
 var executed2 = false;
 var executed3 = false;

function myFunction()
{   
    if(-------------------)
    {
        //Verification - If the others conditions have ever been called
        if (executed2)
        {
            executed2 = false;
        }
        else if(executed3)
        {
            executed3 = false;
        }


        //Verification - If the condition have ever been called during this condition = true;
        if (!execution1) 
        {
            execution1 = true;
            //My code here ...
        }        
    }
    else if (-------------------)
    {

        if (executed1)
        {
            executed1 = false;
        }
        else if(executed3)
        {
            executed3 = false;
        }

        if (!execution2) 
        {
            execution2 = true;
            //My code here ...
        }                            
    }
    else if (-------------------)
    {
        //Same thing with execution3         
    }
}
setInterval("myFunction()", 10000);
```

I'll take the first condition, for example

**(1)** If the condition is true, I want to execute my code but only the first time : as you can see, my function is executed every 10s. As long as the first condition is true, nothing should append more.

If the first condition becomes `false` and the second condition `true`, it’s the same process.

**But now**, If the first condition ever been `true` and `false`, I would like that if the condition becomes `true` again, it will be the same thing that  **(1)**

Is there any way to read a cleaner code to do that ?
Because, now there are only 3 conditions, but there may be 100.

Comment: I present you.. the [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) !

Comment: simply add another variable "hasEverBeenTrue" and add to your if from (1) an "|| hasBeenEverTrue"

Answer (score 1):

use `clearInterval` to stop execution your function and one if to check conditions

```js
var fid = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
var cond = [false,false,false];

function myFunction()
{   
  console.log(cond.join());
  
  // check conditions in some way here (e.g. every is true)
  if(cond.every(x=>x)) { 
    clearInterval(fid);
    console.log('Execute your code and stop');
  } 
  
  // change conditions (example)
  cond[2]=cond[1];
  cond[1]=cond[0];
  cond[0]=true; 

}
```